# Where to ask questions about intercourse after pregnancy?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know someone who is having trouble with sex after pregnancy. I thought this question is related to parenting.stackexchange.com but I was wondering if there is another site that is better suited to these types of questions?

Comment: I think there was a sex / sexual health SE site proposal but it died before it came to fruition IIRC, so it's possible the answer is "nowhere on the network" (surely not on parenting?!)

Comment: It would be best if I refrain from trying to post a wise ass comment to this ;)

Comment: have they tried a doctor? That'd be the place to go for medical advice...

Comment: Sex is off-topic on parenting per their [off-topic subjects at the bottom of the on-topic page](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is a [Sexuality proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality) on Area 51. Your questions might be on-topic there if it goes into beta.

If you are asking about possible dangers or side-effects of intercourse after pregnancy, then you might be able to ask on the new [Health beta](https://health.stackexchange.com/).